# eclipse dynamic web project - default start page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, project

I created in Eclipse dynamic web project, I have index.html in WEB-INF folder.  I click on the main folder of the project Run as > Run on server chose Tomcat v7.0, finish, and it runs OK. But, when I rename index.html to another name I get the message:

> The requested resource (/MyProject/) is not available.

1. How can I change the default page   ?
2. can I put in default page asp file  ?

My web.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyFirstServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>new</description>
    <display-name>GrettingServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>GrettingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GrettingServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In web.xml (under TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/you_application) you have this:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

change to your new file name

Comment: if index.html not found it go to the next one and so on ?

Answer (score 5):

1) How can I change the default page ?

=> change welcome file list in web.xml. Change to your desired filename whichever you are using.

2) can I put in default page asp file ?

=> you can change extension to asp, but you need servlet mapping in web.xml. But if you are talking about `Microsoft ASP pages`, I think you won't be able to add them as per my knowledge as both(jsp and asp) resides under different technologies

**EDIT :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyFirstServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>new</description>
    <display-name>GrettingServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>GrettingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/greetings.asp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here you will make request to `GreetingServlet` using url `http://localhost:8080/myapp/greetings.asp`

Comment: can you explain me what I have to write in servlet mapping ? I edited my post and add the web.xml   .

Comment: @NandkumarTekale sorry to trouble you by writing a comment.I am sure if I write a question then it will be closed.I have developed a project with servlet and JSP but now I am confused on what to run to start the application. in the sense if I run the JSP then data that should come from servlet is not getting loaded again when I run servlet everthing runs but few javascript functions in JSP doesn't get called.Now my confusion here is what should be run to start a application, should I run JSP as the default page or servlet as the default page and what was suggested approach.Can you please guide

Answer (score 3):

Few things to check.

```
1) Servlet mapping extension in web.xml
2) Welcome file definition in web.xml
```

Make sure there extension & name are as you changed.

`web.xml` will be inside `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: I haven't web.xml there .. where I can find him if I work with Tomcat 7 ?

Comment: web.xml will be inside your project--->WEB-INF folder. If it is not there, then you need to create one and add welcome file definition.

Answer (score 0):

this also happens when there is a 404 error, Tomcat searches by default for the index file. jsp/html , you must change it from the Tomcat folder in the web.xml file.inside of Tomcat Eclipse or in installed folder system(c/files Program/apache...) o 
[look at this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMmwA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse-> click on servers-> choose **Tomcat v9.0 Server** at localhost-config-> select **"web.xml"**-> scroll to the bottom or find " "-> **"filename.xml"**

[image]