# Deploying a .war application on a tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I am trying to deploy my hello.war file (Java application) on my tomcat server.

At first I do it from the "Manager App" on tomcat's default page, and it shows off afterwards in the Applications section. (Attached below circled in red)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE2dP.jpg)

But when I try to connect to it by clicking on that link (https://ip-address/hello) it gives me a standard "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" with the description: "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." (picture below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3XxP.png)

I even try putting my hello.war file manually in the server in the appropriate folder location ("/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/webapps") and add read, execute permissions to 'others' on the .war file, add user 'tomcat' as the owner of the file, restart the service. 
But still nothing seems to help and I still get that 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you do not have a default start page in the application. Create `index.html` under `WebContent` and refresh the page. For testing, you can put any content in `index.html` e.g.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello world</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Welcome to my application
    </body>
</html>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632227/eclipse-dynamic-web-project-default-start-page) to learn more about it.

## [Update]

--- Posting the following update based on another request (check comments) from OP ---

As I have mentioned in the comment, you need to forward the request to a JSP (**e.g. queryResults.jsp**) where you want to show the query result. Put the following code at the end in the `doGet` method of your servlet:

```
String nextJSP = "/queryResults.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

This code will automatically forward the request to `queryResults.jsp` where you can access the query result saved in the request/session object.

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Yes that was it!! I am doing this as a project for a company and they only gave me a ImageServlet.java file which is supposed to query a picture from my db. do you know how would be able to add that query's result (by calling the ImageServlet.java file) to my index.html file?

Comment: You are most welcome. Do not add the query result to `index.html`. Keep `index.html` as a generic page. You need forward the request to a new JSP. Let me update my answer to include this as well.

Comment: And how would I be able to attach the image in queryResults.jsp to my HTML page?

Comment: Can you post a new question with your Servlet, HTML and JSP code so that it can attract more attention?

Comment: I just did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063101/creating-an-index-html-file-for-a-war-app-tomcat-that-queries-db

Comment: would adding this to the index.html work after adding your addition? <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/queryResults.jsp">