# Referencing servlet in HTML file for .war file in Tomcat

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have created an index.html file for a Java (.war) application that I deployed on tomcat.

I already have a Java Servlet file that queries a remote db server for a picture i stored there.

The java servlet file is called ImageServlet.java.

I need the HTML page to display that image that the ImageServlet.java queries.

I just don't know how I'm able to reference to the servlet as it retrieves my picture.

Below is the ImageServlet file:

```
package test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet
{
  Connection con = null;

  public Connection getConnection()
  {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      String url = System.getenv("FUJI_MYSQL_URL");
      return DriverManager.getConnection(url,             
System.getenv("FUJI_MYSQL_USER"), System.getenv("FUJI_MYSQL_PASS"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }return null;
  }

  public static byte[] getImageById(Connection con)
  {
    String query = "select photo from photos where picid = 1";
    try
    {
      PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

      stmt.execute();
      ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
      resultSet.first();
      Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob(1);
      stmt.close();
      con.close();
      return blob.getBytes(1L, (int)blob.length());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }return null;
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    Connection con = null;
    con = getConnection();
    byte[] data = getImageById(con);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    baos.write(data);

    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><title>PI_SQLogo.png</title></head><body><img src='data:image/png;base64," + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(baos.toByteArray()) + "'></body></html>");
    out.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: So you have a servlet which creates a HTML page with an embedded image. Does it work if you call the servlet directly? What should your index.html do exactly? How is it related to your servlet? Why do you show us your servlet but you have trouble to write a HTML file? Please explain in detail what you are want to achieve and what your problem is.

Comment: The servlet does not create an HTML file. It simply queries my db for a picture i stored there. The HTML file that i want to create as the main index file of the application should present this picture. I cant seem to understand how i can access and show the picture that my servlet queries in my index.html file

Comment: In your get() method out.println(...) creates a HTML page with an embedded image. Is it possible that you simply copied a random piece of code without really understanding its meaning?

Comment: Yes it is a project I got to complete, and I dont completely understand how to get to my desired result.