# Simple JSP resulting in 404

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm learning JSP and my "Hello World" JSP is giving a 404.I have made sure that my app is deployed on my server.Here my profile.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJZhD.png)
Server:[Deployed on Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdRZj.png)

Comment: did you tried `localhost:8080/DemoJSP/profile.jsp` ?

Comment: I just did and it works that way.But shouldn't the profile.jsp page open by default when I run my project?

Comment: no by default it will find `index` page .You can set welcome page check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632341/10606400)

Comment: I renamed it to `index.jsp` but its still not working.Guess I'll have to set it as welcome page